# Button mousedown not stopping at break point

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a simple spinner plugin and I'm facing an issue.

To reproduce the issue:

1. Click and hold on the "plus" or "minus" button.
2. After reaching the `max` or `min`, the button will be disabled and you will get a message that you reached the maximum or minimum value.
3. Now click only once on the other side to increase or decrease the spinner by only one step.
4. Now click and hold the first button again.
5. The spinner will pass the `max` or `min` by one step and then stop.

What's going wrong?

[image]

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.spiner = function() {
    $(this).each(function() {
      var errors = {
        min: "Looks like you are at Min ",
        max: "looks like you are at Max"
      };
      var temp = 0.0;
      var toUp = null;
      var ivUp = null;
      var toDown = null;
      var ivDown = null;
      var inc = $(this).find('.btn-add');
      var out = $(this).find('.btn-nums');
      var dec = $(this).find('.btn-less');
      var min = $(this).data('min');
      var max = $(this).data('max');
      var step = $(this).data('step');
      var type = $(this).data('type');
      var maxerr = $(this).data('maxerror');
      var minerr = $(this).data('minerror');

      function MaxStop() {
        if (temp >= max) {
          clearTimeout(toUp);
          clearInterval(ivUp);
          $('.btn-add').prop('disabled', true);
          $('.btn-less').prop('disabled', true);
          dec.prop('disabled', false);
          $('.result').html('<div class="alert alert-info animated fadeInUp" role="alert">' + errors.max + '</div>');
        }
      }

      function MinStop() {
        if (temp <= min) {
          clearTimeout(toDown);
          clearInterval(ivDown);
          $('.btn-add').prop('disabled', true);
          $('.btn-less').prop('disabled', true);
          inc.prop('disabled', false);
          $('.result').html('<div class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert">' + errors.min + '</div>');
        }
      }

      function MoreUp() {
        temp = temp + step;

        if (temp > 0) {
          out.html("+" + parseFloat(Math.round(temp * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));
        } else {
          out.html(parseFloat(Math.round(temp * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));
        }

        MaxStop();
      }

      function MoreDown() {
        temp = temp - step;
        if (temp > 0) {
          out.html("+" + parseFloat(Math.round(temp * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));
        } else {
          out.html(parseFloat(Math.round(temp * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));
        }


        MinStop();
      }
      inc.on("mousedown", function() {
          $(".btn-less").prop('disabled', false);
          $(".btn-add").prop('disabled', false);
          $('.result').children().addClass('fadeOutDown');
          temp = temp + step;

          if (temp > 0) {
            out.html("+" + parseFloat(Math.round(temp * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));
          } else {
            out.html(parseFloat(Math.round(temp * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));
          }


          toUp = setTimeout(function() {
            ivUp = setInterval(MoreUp, 75);
          }, 500);

        })
        .on("mouseup mouseleave", function() {
          clearTimeout(toUp);
          clearInterval(ivUp);
          MaxStop();
        });


      dec.on("mousedown", function() {
          $(".btn-less").prop('disabled', false);
          $(".btn-add").prop('disabled', false);
          $('.result').children().addClass('fadeOutDown');
          temp = temp - step;

          if (temp > 0) {
            out.html("+" + parseFloat(Math.round(temp * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));
          } else {
            out.html(parseFloat(Math.round(temp * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));
          }
          toDown = setTimeout(function() {
            ivDown = setInterval(MoreDown, 75);
          }, 500);
        })
        .on("mouseup mouseleave", function() {
          clearTimeout(toDown);
          clearInterval(ivDown);
          MinStop();
        });
    });
  }
}(jQuery));

$('.spiner').spiner();
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.btn-prescriptis .btn {
  border-radius: 0px;
  max-height: 46px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
}

.btn-prescriptis .btn-nums {
  background: #fff !important;
  color: #555 !important;
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group btn-prescriptis spiner" data-min="-6" data-max="3" data-step="0.25" data-maxerror="max" data-minerror="min">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-less">-</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-nums">0.00</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-add">+</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-12 result"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just use  a `input` with a number `type`? Example: `<input type="number" value="0" max="3" min="-6" step=".25"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is happening because the check for if the max or min has been exceeded is not occurring at all the times you think it is. To prevent this, I would add conditional checks in your `MoreUp()` and `MoreDown()` functions so that each time the respective button is clicked, you ensure you're not above or below the limits.

In other words, `if (temp < max) {` and `if (temp > min) {`, as in the snippet below.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.spiner = function() {
    $(this).each(function() {
      var errors = {
        min: "Looks like you are at Min ",
        max: "looks like you are at Max"
      };
      var temp = 0.0;
      var toUp = null;
      var ivUp = null;
      var toDown = null;
      var ivDown = null;
      var inc = $(this).find('.btn-add');
      var out = $(this).find('.btn-nums');
      var dec = $(this).find('.btn-less');
      var min = $(this).data('min');
      var max = $(this).data('max');
      var step = $(this).data('step');
      var type = $(this).data('type');
      var maxerr = $(this).data('maxerror');
      var minerr = $(this).data('minerror');

      function MaxStop() {
        if (temp >= max) {
          clearTimeout(toUp);
          clearInterval(ivUp);
          $('.btn-add').prop('disabled', true);
          $('.btn-less').prop('disabled', true);
          dec.prop('disabled', false);
          $('.result').html('<div class="alert alert-info animated fadeInUp" role="alert">' + errors.max + '</div>');
        }
      }

      function MinStop() {
        if (temp <= min) {
          clearTimeout(toDown);
          clearInterval(ivDown);
          $('.btn-add').prop('disabled', true);
          $('.btn-less').prop('disabled', true);
          inc.prop('disabled', false);
          $('.result').html('<div class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert">' + errors.min + '</div>');
        }
      }

      function MoreUp() {
        if (temp < max) {
          temp = temp + step;

          if (temp > 0) {
            out.html("+" + parseFloat(Math.round(temp * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));
          } else {
            out.html(parseFloat(Math.round(temp * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));
          }

          MaxStop();
        }
      }

      function MoreDown() {
        if (temp > min) {
          temp = temp - step;
          if (temp > 0) {
            out.html("+" + parseFloat(Math.round(temp * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));
          } else {
            out.html(parseFloat(Math.round(temp * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));
          }


          MinStop();
        }
      }
      inc.on("mousedown", function() {
          $(".btn-less").prop('disabled', false);
          $(".btn-add").prop('disabled', false);
          $('.result').children().addClass('fadeOutDown');
          temp = temp + step;

          if (temp > 0) {
            out.html("+" + parseFloat(Math.round(temp * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));
          } else {
            out.html(parseFloat(Math.round(temp * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));
          }


          toUp = setTimeout(function() {
            ivUp = setInterval(MoreUp, 75);
          }, 500);

        })
        .on("mouseup mouseleave", function() {
          clearTimeout(toUp);
          clearInterval(ivUp);
          MaxStop();
        });


      dec.on("mousedown", function() {
          $(".btn-less").prop('disabled', false);
          $(".btn-add").prop('disabled', false);
          $('.result').children().addClass('fadeOutDown');
          temp = temp - step;

          if (temp > 0) {
            out.html("+" + parseFloat(Math.round(temp * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));
          } else {
            out.html(parseFloat(Math.round(temp * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));
          }
          toDown = setTimeout(function() {
            ivDown = setInterval(MoreDown, 75);
          }, 500);
        })
        .on("mouseup mouseleave", function() {
          clearTimeout(toDown);
          clearInterval(ivDown);
          MinStop();
        });
    });
  }
}(jQuery));

$('.spiner').spiner();
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.btn-prescriptis .btn {
  border-radius: 0px;
  max-height: 46px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
}

.btn-prescriptis .btn-nums {
  background: #fff !important;
  color: #555 !important;
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="btn-group btn-prescriptis spiner" data-min="-6" data-max="3" data-step="0.25" data-maxerror="max" data-minerror="min">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-less">-</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-nums">0.00</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-add">+</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-12 result"></div>
</div>
```